# File upload C# .NET Framework 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file

I'm struggeling with .NET 5 (MVC Framework). I would like to upload a file, but I don't know how to retrieve the uploaded file in the controller.
The way it works on previous .NET Versions does not longer work (With HttpPostedFileBase, see an Example [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/259/asp-net-mvc-5-with-ef-6-working-with-files)).

My form is a very small form with a file input:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
public class FittingController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(IndexViewModel viewModel)
    {
        // How to retrieve uploaded file here?
    }
}
```

Has someone already made experiences with .NET Version 5?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `HttpPostedFileBase` is not about `Entity Framework` and you can use it to get posted file, then get `byte[]` and file name from posted file and use them to save the file in database using `EF`. Just as the link your question did it.

Comment: @RezaAghaei you are right, i think it has to do with .NET Version 5. I changed the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution myself. I access the file via the Request:

```
IFormFile file = Request.Form.Files.GetFile("file");
```